# Undefined href in a html table

Tags: php, html, href

I've got a problem with a html table in a php code. 
I try this code but I have a problem with href in a tag. In fact when I click on the href it post undefined while DetailsAnnonces.php exist.

Thanks for your response.

```
<?php 

            $conn=@mysqli_connect($_SESSION['servername'],$_SESSION['username'],
                $_SESSION['password'], $_SESSION['database']) or die(mysql_error());
                $verifExistence1 = "SELECT * FROM `annonces`;";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $verifExistence1);

                echo "<table border = 2>";
                echo "<table  align='center'>   <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Titre</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Image</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>";
                while($row =  @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $idbis=$row['id'];
                $titrebis=$row['titre'];
                echo "<tr>
                <td>" . $row['titre'] . "</td><td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>
                <td> <a   href=\"DetailsAnnonces.php?id=$idbis\">$titrebis</a>
                </tr>";

                }
                echo "</table>";
                //echo $html_table;
                ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it post undefined' ?

Comment: when I click on the href it open a blank page with the word undefined

Comment: It sounds like your `$idbis` variable is undefined. Try `var_dump($idbis);` and report back what you see. If it's undefined then there's a problem somewhere along your database query or the field `id` does not exist in the database.

Comment: I tried var_dump($idbis) but stil got the same problem (undefined). I checked the variable id with a echo $idbis and there is no problem with that: it works. Here a picture of my workspace it could be useful [link](http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=16/06/o54f.png)

Comment: What do you see in the browser's "view source" for that href? I mean, when you look at this page in your browser, you can right-click the link which has the problem, and select "examine this element" (or something like this, depending on your browser type), and browser will show you the HTML source for this line. What does it show? And also, when you see that blank page with the word "undefined", what do you see at the address bar of this page?

Comment: when a view source of that href it gives me                                               <a href="DetailsAnnonces.php?id=34">feru</a>                                       so the right id and the right titre. For the blank page I've got http://localhost/insacoin/Annonces.php so the same page.

Comment: In this case, the problem is not where you are looking for it. The problem is in the DetailsAnnonces.php script. This script outputs the word "undefined" for some reason.

Comment: apart a head html code I've nothing on DetailsAnnonces.php and I think the problem is not there because when I access directly to DetailsAnnonces.php it works.

Comment: Does it work if you open the address "DetailsAnnonces.php?id=34"?

Comment: Yes it open the DetailsAnnonces.php page.

Comment: It most probably not the right reason, but yet, try to close the td tag after the link.

Comment: Do you have any javascript on this page?

Comment: Yess I tried a javascript script and I forgot to delete it. Thanks a looot @KostaShah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a javascript left on this page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the $idbis

```
<?php
 echo "
 <td> 
     <a href='DetailsAnnonces.php?id=".$idbis.">'".$titrebis."</a>
 </td>
</tr>";
?>
```

Comment: I tried ur code but now I've got another problem. The href doesn't appear on the table. Here a image of my workspace [link](http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=16/06/lyu3.png)